# I want to populate my drop-down list according to selection on radio button, but my code is not working

Tags: javascript, jquery

I was trying to make a dynamic page using PHP and JS (and HTML, CSS).
I wanted to populate a drop-down list on the basis of radio button selected. But the console on Chrome shows the following message:

> "Uncaught Syntax Error: Unexpected Error<"

```
function create_s()
        {
            $('#checking').empty();
            var number = $('#comparea').find('option:selected').attr('number_s');
            //attr('number_s');
            if(number==3){
                $('#checking').append('<input type="radio" class="radio"  id="hd" name="civil" value="sanitation" />sanitation');
                $('#checking').append('<input type="radio" class="radio" name="civil" value="horitculture"/>horitculture');
                $('#checking').append('<input type="radio" class="radio" name="civil" value="water"/>water');
            }
            if(number==2){
                $('#checking').append('<input type="radio" name="telecom" value="telephone"/>telephone');
                $('#checking').append('<input type="radio" name="telecom" value="internet"/>internet');
            }
            if(number==1){
                $('#checking').append('<input type="radio" name="electrical" value="meter"/>meter');
            }
            RadioLoadData();

        }
$('.radio').change(function(){
                    var value = $( this ).attr('value');
                    //var value = ('input[name=civil]:checked', '#myForm').val();
                    document.write("dfhasldhjkh");
                    if(value=="sanitation" || value==="sanitation"){

                        selectcall(100);
                    }
                    if(value=="horitculture" || value==="horitculture"){

                        selectcall(200);
                    }  
                    //alert($('input[name=radioName]:checked', '#myForm').val()); 
            });


function selectcall(value)
            {

               if(value==100){
                $('#selectlist').empty();
                var pcode="<?php              
                mysqli_select_db($conn, $database);
                $sql1 = "SELECT * FROM complaint_area_category WHERE complaint_category_id>100 and complaint_category_id<200 order by complaint_category  ";
                $record = mysqli_query($conn, $sql1);
                while($data=mysqli_fetch_assoc($record)){
                    echo "<option name=".$data['complaint_category_id'].">".$data['complaint_category']."</option>";
                        }
                ?>"
                $('#selectlist').append(pcode);
                }
            }





<select id="selectlist" class="box" style="top:200px" required=""><br><br>
        <option selected="selected" value="">-Select-</option>
        <script >
            //Here different select lists are populated.
        </script>
```

Comment: Do you understand the difference between client side and server side scripting, and when / how they execute?

Comment: it's simple you can not do php query and php coding inside JavaScript function. Use ajax for this purpose.You can use only php variables if they are presented on that page only in your javascript/jQuery code

Comment: yes brother I do understand the difference between the two.

@AlivetoDie but my PHP code is working as I wanted it to do, the difficulty I am facing is that the variable value is not able to fetch the value from the radio button

Comment: then why you putted question here? if It's working. Because you are assuming that it working but it not.Check your browser console and you will come to know your problems. That is what `Ajax` ment for

Comment: Your PHP code will only run once per request. It will run on the server during the page load, then send the resulting string as part of the content to the browser. When you run that function through JS, the PHP will NOT run again.

Comment: @Enstage it is working fine, i Just was to know why the variable value is not able to fetch the value.

Comment: What variable value fetching what from where...?

Comment: The variable 'value' is supposed to fetch the attribute 'value' from the radio button

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution to get it done...

```
$('#checking').append('<input type="radio" class="radio"  id="cis" name="civil" value="sanitation" onclick="onChange()"/>sanitation');

 function onChange()
            {

                if($('#cis').is(':checked')){
                    selectcall(100);
                }
                if($('#cih').is(':checked')){
                    selectcall(200);
                }

            }
```

and then the selectcall() funtion as in the question.

Answer (score -1):

Here is updated code try it.

```
function selectcall(value)
{

    if(value==100){
        $('#selectlist').empty();
        var pcode="<?php"
        mysqli_select_db($conn, $database);
        $sql1 = "SELECT * FROM complaint_area_category WHERE complaint_category_id>100 and complaint_category_id<200 order by complaint_category  ";
        $record = mysqli_query($conn, $sql1);
        $('#selectlist').append('<option selected="selected" value="">-Select-</option');
        while($data=mysqli_fetch_assoc($record)){
            echo ='<option name="'+$data['complaint_category_id']+'">'+$data['+complaint_category']+'"</option>';
        }
        "?>"
        $('#selectlist').append(pcode);
    }
}

<select id="selectlist" class="box" style="top:200px" required=""></select>
```

Comment: What in the world is this...? This will not work, ever. Please research the difference between client side and server side scripting.

Comment: When this runs PHP will chuck an error because of the random double quote after `<?php`. Your answer demonstrates no understanding of how PHP or Javascript works, it is wrong, and will not work.

Comment: really this will not work, this will simply give a syntax error, have you tried to use it ?

Comment: dude! I don't know about PHP but I know about jquery that's why I posted it. I thought that if PHP right then my code works. sorry for this wrong post.

Comment: don't be rude buddy it's Ok. Be Cool.

Comment: I'm perfectly fine and calm. You've just added confusion pointlessly, and still haven't deleted the answer.

Comment: @Enstage dude,I thought you were working on the code ..!